# Converting a string into numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

```
# replacing all digits in a string with their complement in 9.
.data
    string: .asciiz "123471863"

.text
main:
    # load string's 1st address into the memory
    la $a0, string

    # initialize the loop-counter
    li $t0, 0
    li $t1, 9 # complement envelope for later use

    # start the loop    
start_loop: 
    lb $t2, ($a0) # Take one character from string

    # loop termination condition
    beq $t2, $zero, end_loop # terminate if null-value found

    subi $t2, $t2, 48 # convert it to a digit
    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
    sw $t2,($a0) # restore the string-byte content

    addi $a0, $a0, 1 # go to next string-byte
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment loop-counter

    j start_loop
end_loop: 

    # print string  
    la $a0, string # load 1st address of the string
    li $v0, 4 # syscall for string print   
    syscall

    move $a0, $t0 # load 1st address of the string
    li $v0, 1 # syscall for string print   
    syscall

    # exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

The program isn't working as expected. After 1st iteration, the `$a0` register isn't giving the correct value. Apparently, `sw $t2,($a0)` is destroying the original address.

How can I get over this issue?

Comment: "null",  in the sense of the comment, *is* a zero value.  For handling strings with embedded zero bytes (i.e. strings where the characters can be *any* byte value) you need to use a different way of encoding strings,  the most common being to prefix the string with a length value.

Comment: @JoshGreifer, how to do that?

Comment: Well, that's another question which you can post here - but I suggest you first look for questions here on "pascal strings"

Comment: @JoshGreifer, "*that's another question which you can post here*" --- this is not another question. On the basis of your comment, this is already part of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to differentiate a null and a '0'. null is 0, while '\0' is 48.

Your test

```
    beq $t2, $zero, end_loop # terminate if null-value found
```

is perfectly correct and will detect the end of string.

What is incorrect is you algorithm.

A way to complement a number in C, would be :

```
while(c=*str){
  c=c-'0' ; // transform the number to integer
  c=9-c;    // complement it
  c += '0'; // add 48 to turn it back to a character
  str++;
}
```

You are missing the last conversion to character.

If you change

```
    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
```

to

```
    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
    addi $t2, $t2, 48
```

all should work.

Alternatively, ou can simplify your algorithm and remark that the computation `c=9-(c-48)+48` is equivalent to `c=105-c`. Add before start_loop

```
   li $t4 105 ##
```

and replace the three lines

```
    subi $t2, $t2, 48 # convert it to a digit
    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
    addi $t2, $t2, 48
```

by

```
   sub $t2,$t4,$t2  # complement to 9 directly on char representing the digit
```

Comment: `li $t4 105 ##` ?

Comment: Ooops, a comma is missing. `li $t4,105` The problem is that you can subtract an immediate from a register, but not subtract a register *from* an immediate in an instruction. So you put the immediate 105 in a register before the loop to perform the subtraction in an instruction.

Comment: *If you change

    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
to

    sub $t2, $t1, $t2 # apply complement to $t2
    addi $t2, $t2, 48
all should work.* --- nope. doesn't work.

Comment: Onec corrected, your algorithm really seems correct, but I do not have time to test it. Maybe the problem comes from branches. Are your branches delayed ?

Comment: *Are your branches delayed?* --- nope.